# Apple Mail plist entry to load remote content

Tags: plist, apple-mail

So I know how to have apple mail 9 always load remote content, but I need to set that preference programmatically. I'm looking through the apple mail plist file but can't seem to find the value. Does anyone have an idea where this setting might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I diffed `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist` after enabling 'Load remote content' in Mail preferences, and got this:

```
        <key>AlertForNonmatchingDomains</key>
        <false/>
        <key>DisableURLLoading</key>
-       <true/>
+       <false/>
        <key>ExpandPrivateAliases</key>
        <true/>
```